# Extending length of wire where the spark is produced on a mini tesla coil

Tags: coil, tesla-coil, spark

How can I extend / increase the length of wire where the spark comes from on my mini musical tesla coil?  See my mini tesla coil below along with the quick connector I'm using to extend the wire with.  When I try and extend the wire using a quick connector the spark goes out (I was only trying to extend the length of the wire about a 1 foot.

PS: I believe the circuit is a Slayer Exciter.

[image: Tesla coil kit]

[image: Quick connector I'm using to extend the length of the wire on the coil]

Comment: Have you considered soldering? What are the those shoes for?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič The four shoes / screws at the bottom on the circuit board are just for stability on a flat surface or to mount it to something.  I don't want to solder anything until I know it will work that’s why I used a quick connector to extend the length of the wire shown in the second picture.

Comment: @RickT By "shoes" I think he was referring to the connector in the second picture. It looks a little bit like a pair of shoes =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circuit is not a slayer exciter, it is a PLL-driven SSTC.

I expect your spark is going out because this is a PLL-driven coil. It is designed for a very specific frequency. When you extend the output wire you change the resonant frequency of the system and you will probably lose your phase lock. In order to extend the wire you would have to carefully adjust the capacitor and resistor values on the PLL chip (probably a 4046) in order to move the frequency capture/lock range back to where it needs to be.

In other words, you can't simply extend the wire, and unless you're well-versed in phase-locked loops and how this particular circuit works, and how to modify it to meet your needs, you will not be able to make this change.